# R delete the bottom x% of a data frame column and double the top

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to drop the bottom 5% of my column values and double the entries with the top 5% in values. I tried:

```
top_n(sa$Net,5)
```

but I only get the message :

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

I have dplyr installed and loaded

Comment: `top_n` expects a `data.frame`, not a vector as you've provided. How about `top_n(sa, 5, Net)`?

Comment: Yes that works but gives me the entire rows :) I just want the top 5 or bottom 5 values of that column not of the frame

Comment: pull the column: `sa %>% top_n(5, Net)  %>% pull(Net)`

Comment: throws me the error : Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a double vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
iris %>% bind_rows(top_n(.,5,Sepal.Length)) %>% top_n(.,nrow(.)-5,Sepal.Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `top_n(sa, 5, Net) %>% pull(Net)`